# migrate a template to c++11 variadic template

Tags: templates, c++11

I have a template that looks like this:

```
template <typename T, typename ARG1, typename ARG2>
class Base
{
public:
    Base(const std::shared_ptr<ARG1>& arg1, const std::shared_ptr<ARG2>& arg2)
        : mArg1(arg1)
        , mArg2(arg2)
    {
    }

    struct Hasher
    {
        std::size_t operator()(const std::shared_ptr<T>& object) const
        {
            std::hash<std::shared_ptr<ARG1>> hash1;
            auto seed = hash1(object->mArg1);

            std::hash<std::shared_ptr<ARG2>> hash2;
            boost::hash_combine(seed, hash2(object->mArg2));

            return seed;
        }

        bool operator()(const std::shared_ptr<T>& object1,
                        const std::shared_ptr<T>& object2) const
        {
            return object1->mArg1 == object2->mArg1 && object1->mArg2 == object2->mArg2;
        }
    };

protected:
    std::shared_ptr<ARG1> mArg1;
    std::shared_ptr<ARG2> mArg2;
};
```

I am new to variadic templates with c++11. Can someone bootstrap me a bit with how this template will looks like to support N arguments - if possible.

Comment: Use `tuple<shared_ptr<Args>...>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approximation, but I'm using `hash_append` documented here:

[N3980](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3980.html)

[Presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Njjp_MJsgt8&feature=youtu.be)

[Slides](https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2014/blob/master/Presentations/Types%20Don't%20Know%20%23/Types%20Don't%20Know%20%23%20-%20Howard%20Hinnant%20-%20CppCon%202014.pdf?raw=true)

[github library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/hash_append)

which makes things both simpler and far more flexible.

```
#include "hash_append.h"
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T, typename ARG1, typename ARG2, typename ...Args>
class Base
{
public:
    Base(const std::shared_ptr<ARG1>& arg1, const std::shared_ptr<ARG2>& arg2,
         const std::shared_ptr<Args>& ...args)
        : mArgs(arg1, arg2, args...)
    {
    }

    template <class H>
    friend
    void
    hash_append(H& h, const Base& b)
    {
        hash_append(h, b.mArgs);
    }

protected:
    std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<ARG1>, std::shared_ptr<ARG2>,
               std::shared_ptr<Args>...> mArgs;
};
```

I arbitrarily chose a minimum number of args as 2.